# boton exportar a excel de Datatable se bloquea cuando se trata de mas de 100 mil registros

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datatable

la funcion del datatable es de la forma:

```
function mostrar_datatable_marcaciones() {
    "use strict";
    $('#resultado_marcacion').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        "language": {
            "url": url_js + "/es_es.lang",
        },
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, "Todos"]
        ],
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    });
}
```

cuando se trata de registros de marcaciones de alrededor de 2000 registros, funciona, pero mayor cantidad el navegador se cuelga...

Comment: creo que es mas que obvio por eso se utliza paginacion! :v

Comment: Tal y como dice @Bryro el problema es precisamente la cantidad de registros. La solución es también la que dice él, utilizar paginación. No puedes confiar una carga tan grande en el cliente. Lo ideal sería que desde cliente fueses pidiendo una cantidad de registros controlables (10, 50, 100, no muchos más), para asegurar una respuesta fluida para el usuario.

Comment: Una buena alternativa a la paginación es obtener registros mediante filtros de fecha (inicio | fin).. aunque si filtran por x años y dependiendo la cantidad de registros deberás implementar también la paginación mencionada

Comment: la paginacion funciona perfectamente, el problema es al pulsar el boton de descargar a excel, durante el proceso de descarga aparece el mensaje del navegador, sobre lentitud del script y emite los mensajes de detener o depurar..